# how to add click event on echarts heatmap cell?

Tags: reactjs, echarts

how do I register an onclick event when i click one of the cell? This is the [current example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian) I am following. for example, trigger a alert when i click on one particular cell

Answer (score 0):

Following this [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events) , This is how I did it.

Below is my code

```
...

triggerOnClick = () =>{
    console.log("enter");
  }

  onClick = {
    'click': this.triggerOnClick.bind(this)
  }



  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ReactEcharts
          option={getOtion()}
          style={{ height: "700px", width: "100%" }}
          onEvents={this.onClick}
     
      </div>
  )}
```

This click event is only for individual cells in a heatmap